# Cropping an ellipse from an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, face-detection, matlab-cvst

I want to extract an elliptical region from an image (a portion of a face portion from an image) preferably in MATLAB:

[image]

For example, in this image, I want to extract the region within red boundary.
Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Please elaborate, give examples, show image, etc...

Comment: Do you want to find the face manually or automatically?

Comment: How is the ellipse given? Is is inserted using `imellipse`? Would you know the geometry of it (location + major and minor axis)? You could use the `createMask` method on the resulting `imellipse` object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cropping is easy, all you have to do is apply a proper mask. The trick is to create such a mask.

Assuming `A` is your image, try this:

```
%# Create an ellipse shaped mask
c = fix(size(A) / 2);   %# Ellipse center point (y, x)
r_sq = [76, 100] .^ 2;  %# Ellipse radii squared (y-axis, x-axis)
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:size(A, 2), 1:size(A, 1));
ellipse_mask = (r_sq(2) * (X - c(2)) .^ 2 + ...
    r_sq(1) * (Y - c(1)) .^ 2 <= prod(r_sq));

%# Apply the mask to the image
A_cropped = bsxfun(@times, A, uint8(ellipse_mask));
```

The cropped image will be stored in `A_cropped`.
Play with the coordinates of the center and the values of the radii until you get the desired result.

**EDIT**: I extended the solution for RGB images (if matrix `A` is 3-D).

Comment: I tried your code. It gives error with the last line: A_cropped(ellipse_mask) = A;
??? In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B
must be the same.

Comment: Your code works now. But now I just get a completely opaque red ellipse with a black background.

Comment: Does the original image display ok with `imshow(A)`? `imagesc` works fine for me, and shows the cropped face correctly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12695/discussion-between-user671805-and-eitant)

Comment: Note that, if the mask cannot be reused (e.g. because there is exactly one ellipse per image), you may save some time and memory by not storing it explicitly, and cropping in-place: A(~(r_sq(2) * (X - c(2) etc etc)) = 0;

Comment: Can we do the same thing with imellipse function? If we do how ?

Answer (score 2):

This the method I use to crop faces into ellipse shape. It makes the background transparent.

```
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile({'*.jpg;*.tif;*.png;*.gif','All Image Files'},'Please Select an Image');
image = imread([PathName FileName]); 
imshow(image) %needed to use imellipse
user_defined_ellipse = imellipse(gca, []); % creates user defined ellipse object.
wait(user_defined_ellipse);% You need to click twice to continue. 
MASK = double(user_defined_ellipse.createMask());
new_image_name = [PathName 'Cropped_Image_' FileName];
new_image_name = new_image_name(1:strfind(new_image_name,'.')-1); %removing the .jpg, .tiff, etc 
new_image_name = [new_image_name '.png']; % making the image .png so it can be transparent
imwrite(image, new_image_name,'png','Alpha',MASK);
msg = msgbox(['The image was written to ' new_image_name],'New Image Path');
waitfor(msg);
```