# Extract elliptical region and crop it with with manually in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, crop, extract, matlab-cvst

I have many face images, I want to extract an elliptical region from the images by manually and crop and save it automatically(like imcrop but not a rectangle). 
Could you help me about this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: There is an app for labeling objects in images in the latest version of the Computer Vision System Toolbox, but it only does rectangles. http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/label-images-for-classification-model-training.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079781/cropping-an-ellipse-from-an-image

Comment: Yes I know the solution for rectangle but I need an ellipse one. Does imellipse function give me the coordinates?  @Dima

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `imellipse` function.

Answer (score 2):

```
%This is what you would do after creating the mask to get the coordinates.

structBoundaries = bwboundaries(binaryImage);
xy=structBoundaries{1}; % Get n by 2 array of x,y coordinates.
x = xy(:, 2); % Columns.
y = xy(:, 1); % Rows.
```

However a better way would be to use the code below. Essentially, it asks the user to select an image and then the user crops the image manually and then it saves to the location of where the original image is.

```
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile({'*.jpg;*.tif;*.png;*.gif','All Image Files'},'Please Select an Image');
image = imread([PathName FileName]); 
imshow(image) %needed to use imellipse
user_defined_ellipse = imellipse(gca, []); % creates user defined ellipse object.
wait(user_defined_ellipse);% You need to click twice to continue. 
MASK = double(user_defined_ellipse.createMask());
new_image_name = [PathName 'Cropped_Image_' FileName];
new_image_name = new_image_name(1:strfind(new_image_name,'.')-1); %removing the .jpg, .tiff, etc 
new_image_name = [new_image_name '.png']; % making the image .png so it can be transparent
imwrite(image, new_image_name,'png','Alpha',MASK);
msg = msgbox(['The image was written to ' new_image_name],'New Image Path');
waitfor(msg);
```